# Read Android Expansion File - PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, apk-expansion-files

I would like a way to access my expansion file in Cordova.

The issue is that the plugin I've heard most people recommend;

https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader

requires a bit more effort to get it working, namely modifying boilerplate Cordova files. I don't get to see or access these files with PhoneGap Build as it generates and compiles these files, along with my www files, into an apk in one go.

Is there a way to get this plugin working with PhoneGap Build, and if not, is there an alternative that I could perhaps use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. I'll leave the answer here for anyone that may have a the same problem I did.

So this plugin: https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader

Works just fine with Phonegap Build. The issue was actually with the methods I was trying to use in setting it up correctly. The correct steps to take are as follows:

In your root/config.xml file, add the following:

```
<plugin name="com.flyingsoftgames.xapkeader" spec="https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader.git#cordova-6.5.0">
    <variable name="XAPK_EXPANSION_AUTHORITY" value="YOUR_APP_NAME" />
    <variable name="XAPK_PUBLIC_KEY" value="YOUR_GOOGLE_KEY"/>
</plugin>
```

Wherever you want a file to access the apk expansion file, use the following syntax:

```
content://YOUR_APP_NAME/path/to/file.jpg
```

This is fairly clear about it in the documentation, but it's worth noting that you set the path correctly. A lot of tutorials online will have you write something like:

```
content://YOUR_APP_NAME/main_expansion/path/to/file.jpg
```

This made me believe that the **main_expansion** portion of the path was a syntax meant for the plugin to access the main expansion file and not the patch expansion file, but this is resolved by the plugin as it prefers files in the patch to the main automatically.

The **main_expansion** portion is there because that's the file path that the tutorials online created. So their actual file path would be

> main_expansion/images/funny_image.jpg

whereas mine was something like

> audio_files/dialog/hello.mp3

It sounds so simple but this caused me an unnecessary amount of trouble.

Also, it's worth noting that it didn't work when I was using Cordova cli 6.2.0, but worked when I upgraded to 6.5.0. This is done in your root/config.xml file:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful, but I am confused about one issue. PhoneGap Build requires you include all the files it processes in a single www directory, with index.html at its root, etc. So where does the directory with the expansion file (in my case a 90 meg audio file) go to? If I put it in the www directory then it is too large to upload to the PhoneGap Build cloud. But if I don't put it in there, then it does not get uploaded. Help...

Comment: Hey Peter! I'm glad I could help!

This was a while ago, but if my memory serves me correctly, you don't upload the expansion file to PhoneGap Build but only when you're uploading to the Google Playstore.

Check out: https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files
for more info. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the latest version of the Playstore console does not give any options to upload expansion files. You can send up APK files, and that is all. It appears they want us now to use bundles, not expansion files. Anyway I solved the problem by compressing the audio file so that all is under 50MB and all works fine. Thanks! Peter